Having trouble sending SMS from serial, Arduino, Python
I have a python script producing an output which I want to send as SMS. Here is the Python code to send message over serial port.
    def blinkLED(color):
        ser.open()
        ser.write(color.encode()) # send color to Arduino to control LED
        time.sleep(0.1)
        ser.close()
        print("LED Blinked")

RX blinks on the board when script runs,  Here is the Arduino code to send sms 
void updateSerial() {
  delay(500);
  while(Serial.available()) {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());}
    while (mySerial.available()){
    Serial.write(mySerial.read()) ;// Forward data from Arduino Serial to SIM900
  }
  
}


void loop() {
if(Serial.available() > 0){
    updateSerial();
    String message = Serial.readString();
    message.trim();
    if (message == "GREEN"){
      mySerial.println("AT");
      mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
      delay(100);
      mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+254703XXXXX\"");
      delay(100);
      //updateSerial();
      mySerial.println("Can do exam");
      delay(100);
      mySerial.println((char)26);
      Serial.println("Message sent");
      delay(100);   //updateSerial();

    }else if (message == "RED"){
      mySerial.println("AT");
      mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
      delay(100);
      mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+2547------\"");
      delay(100);
      //updateSerial();
      mySerial.println("Can't do exam");
      delay(100);
      mySerial.println((char)26);
      delay(100);
    }
}
}

Test messages have been sent using the same setup. I still can't receive a message
I narrowed to using GREEN and RED to see if any message would be sent. I have tried multiple solutions no progress
I also tried while(Serial.avaialable()==0)

Have you tested the SIM in a phone or tablet prior to this? Is it protected by a PIN?

The SIM works fine, can all or send SMS. The pin is not a protected one

The reason I asked is that if the SIM is protected, you need a separate command to unlock it using the PIN code. What were the debugging results? I recommend to increase all of the delays to 5000 for testing. 100 might be unrealistic. When sending an SMS you actually need to wait for the ">" to then send the message. CMGS should also respond with an "OK" so there might be a longer delay there too. The best way to tell is to debug it. Also, your code could be hugely simplified since it's almost identical in ifs and you can use a constant for the delay to not change it in 50 places each time.

I changed the way I opened serial communication in my python script. When sending the data before
def triggerSMS(message):
    ser.open()
    ser.write(message.encode('utf-8'))
    ser.close()

I commented out ser.open() and ser.close()
